# Double Integral Formula for Holomorphic Function on the Unit Disc (Complex Plain)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula, greens-theorem

While studying some complex analysis , I encountered the following problem:

"*Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$.Prove that for every $\zeta \in \mathbb{D}$ the following formula is valid*:
$f(\zeta)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int \int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{f(z)}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^2}dxdy$ "

I tried this by using Green's Theorem and a Cauchy-Green theorem, but i ended up with a double integral expression of the form
$\int \int_{\mathbb{D}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\frac{1}{z-\zeta}dx dy$

Comment: What do you get with [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) exactly ?

Comment: I consider the Cauchy Integral Formula as a contour integral and i use Green's Theorem to get the statement that i posted under the question. It is a bit long to post it in this comment. I used Sarason's book to find a similar statement but nothing occured .

Comment: With Green's theorem you are supposed to write $\frac{f(z)}{(1-\overline{z}\zeta)^2}$ as $\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}$ and obtain a contour integral

Comment: I did this but on $\oint \frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}dz$ so i guess that's why i was wrong. I will try your hint, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with $\oint \frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta} dz $ ? And do you know [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) ?

Comment: Of course i know it. I considered $f(\zeta)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}dz$ and then i used Green's theorem and got: $f(\zeta)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}dx+\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{if(z)}{z-\zeta}dy$ which from Green's Theorem gives us : $\int \int_{\mathbb{D}} i \frac{\partial{\frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}}}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\partial{\frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}}}{\partial{y}}dxdy$ or $\frac{1}{\pi}\int \int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{\partial{f(z)}}{\partial{\bar{z}}}dxdy$

Comment: You need to assume more of $f$, like $f\in L^1(\mathbb D,dxdy).$

Comment: The problem's statement  is exactly what I posted .

Comment: Even if that's what the problem said, you need to assume more of $f.$ Otherwise the integral may not be defined.

Comment: I just can't think about it. I think there is no reason to assume something nore than that.

Comment: Maybe you mean $f \in H(\mathbb{D}) $

Comment: No, that just means $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D.$ The point is $f$ could be badly unbounded in the disc, and that integral may not be defined.

Comment: I know! Nothing more was written i am sure about that!

Comment: @zhw.  How can an analytic function on the disk be unbounded there?

Comment: Consider a function with a pole on the boundary, like $1/(1-z)^2.$(In fact for this $f,$ the integral we are considering here is not defined as a Lebesgue integral.)

Comment: The function $\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^2}$ is the Bergman kernel on the unit disk. See [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2015-16/reproducing_kernels.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with Green's Formula also. Using the Cauchy Integral Formula one has
$$f(\zeta)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}{\frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}}dz=\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)\bar{z}}{1-\bar{z}\zeta}dz$$ The last statement can be justified by the fact that $z=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ when $|z|=1$ . Now one can use Green's theorem . After some fun one has 
$$f(\zeta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int \int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{\partial{\frac{f(z)\bar{z}}{1-\bar{z}\zeta}}}{\partial{\bar{z}}}dxdy=\frac{1}{\pi}\int \int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{f(z)}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^2
}dxdy.$$  My effort was still good, i just did not consider the simple step $$z=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$$ when $|z|=1$.  Thanks also for the answer using the series representation it was a simple and beautiful way to solve this excercise.

Answer (score 5):

Sketch: Assume first $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $\overline {\mathbb D}.$ Write $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n.$ Recall that

$$\frac{1}{(1-u)^2} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)u^n.$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{(1-\bar z{\zeta})^2} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(\bar z{\zeta})^n.$$

Now compute

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb D}\left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n \right )\left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(\bar z{\zeta})^n \right )\, dA(z)$$

using polar coordinates and orthogonality of the functions $z^n$ with respect to area measure on $\mathbb D.$ This works out nicely.

Comment: This should be tractable.  +1

Comment: Never thought of taking the series representation!